# get country code from country name in android

Tags: android, country-codes

I know there is a way to obtain the country name from a country code, but is it also possible the other way arround? I have found so far no function that converts a String like "Netherlands" into "NL". If possible, how can I obtain the country codes?

Comment: the Locale class could help you.

Comment: I looked through it, but found no method that should do the trick.

Comment: you can list the available locales and compare the display country name.

Answer (score 14):

```
public String getCountryCode(String countryName) {

    // Get all country codes in a string array.
    String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
    Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<>();
    Locale locale; 
    String name;

    // Iterate through all country codes:
    for (String code : isoCountryCodes) {
        // Create a locale using each country code
        locale = new Locale("", code);
        // Get country name for each code.
        name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        // Map all country names and codes in key - value pairs.
        countryMap.put(name, code);
    }

    // Return the country code for the given country name using the map.
    // Here you will need some validation or better yet 
    // a list of countries to give to user to choose from.
    return countryMap.get(countryName); // "NL" for Netherlands.
}
```

Or a Kotlin one liner:

```
fun getCountryCode(countryName: String) = 
     Locale.getISOCountries().find { Locale("", it).displayCountry == countryName }
```

As noted in the comments, if you're using Java, depending on how often you call this method, you might want to pull the map out of it but better yet look at the optimised version by @Dambo without the map.

Comment: @Vllad ... No need to create a new map every time in the loop. It will always have the size of 1 that way and keep the last entry saved. You need to create hashmap outside the loop. I have updated your answer

Comment: Create `HashMap` every time you call the method is very bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

I improved *Vlad* answer. Because initialize `HashMap` every time you access the method is very bad practice. Unless you initializing the map once. The edited answer:

```
public String getCountryCode(String countryName) {
    String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (String code : isoCountryCodes) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("", code);
        if (countryName.equalsIgnoreCase(locale.getDisplayCountry())) {
           return code;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: this won't work if the device's language is not english

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code, and it works for me.

```
public String GetCountryZipCode() {
    String CountryID = "";
    String CountryZipCode = "";

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //getNetworkCountryIso
    CountryID = manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();
    Log.v(Constant.TAG, "CountryID" + CountryID);
    String[] rl = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    for (int i = 0; i < rl.length; i++) {
        String[] g = rl[i].split(",");
        if (g[1].trim().equals(CountryID.trim())) {
            CountryZipCode = g[0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return CountryZipCode;
}
```

and for `CountryCodes` you have to put following string in string xml

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
    <item>93,AF</item>
    <item>355,AL</item>
    <item>213,DZ</item>
    <item>376,AD</item>
    <item>244,AO</item>
    <item>672,AQ</item>
    <item>54,AR</item>
    <item>374,AM</item>
    <item>297,AW</item>
    <item>61,AU</item>
    <item>43,AT</item>
    <item>994,AZ</item>
    <item>973,BH</item>
    <item>880,BD</item>
    <item>375,BY</item>
    <item>32,BE</item>
    <item>501,BZ</item>
    <item>229,BJ</item>
    <item>975,BT</item>
    <item>591,BO</item>
    <item>387,BA</item>
    <item>267,BW</item>
    <item>55,BR</item>
    <item>673,BN</item>
    <item>359,BG</item>
    <item>226,BF</item>
    <item>95,MM</item>
    <item>257,BI</item>
    <item>855,KH</item>
    <item>237,CM</item>
    <item>1,CA</item>
    <item>238,CV</item>
    <item>236,CF</item>
    <item>235,TD</item>
    <item>56,CL</item>
    <item>86,CN</item>
    <item>61,CX</item>
    <item>61,CC</item>
    <item>57,CO</item>
    <item>269,KM</item>
    <item>242,CG</item>
    <item>243,CD</item>
    <item>682,CK</item>
    <item>506,CR</item>
    <item>385,HR</item>
    <item>53,CU</item>
    <item>357,CY</item>
    <item>420,CZ</item>
    <item>45,DK</item>
    <item>253,DJ</item>
    <item>670,TL</item>
    <item>593,EC</item>
    <item>20,EG</item>
    <item>503,SV</item>
    <item>240,GQ</item>
    <item>291,ER</item>
    <item>372,EE</item>
    <item>251,ET</item>
    <item>500,FK</item>
    <item>298,FO</item>
    <item>679,FJ</item>
    <item>358,FI</item>
    <item>33,FR</item>
    <item>689,PF</item>
    <item>241,GA</item>
    <item>220,GM</item>
    <item>995,GE</item>
    <item>49,DE</item>
    <item>233,GH</item>
    <item>350,GI</item>
    <item>30,GR</item>
    <item>299,GL</item>
    <item>502,GT</item>
    <item>224,GN</item>
    <item>245,GW</item>
    <item>592,GY</item>
    <item>509,HT</item>
    <item>504,HN</item>
    <item>852,HK</item>
    <item>36,HU</item>
    <item>91,IN</item>
    <item>62,ID</item>
    <item>98,IR</item>
    <item>964,IQ</item>
    <item>353,IE</item>
    <item>44,IM</item>
    <item>972,IL</item>
    <item>39,IT</item>
    <item>225,CI</item>
    <item>81,JP</item>
    <item>962,JO</item>
    <item>7,KZ</item>
    <item>254,KE</item>
    <item>686,KI</item>
    <item>965,KW</item>
    <item>996,KG</item>
    <item>856,LA</item>
    <item>371,LV</item>
    <item>961,LB</item>
    <item>266,LS</item>
    <item>231,LR</item>
    <item>218,LY</item>
    <item>423,LI</item>
    <item>370,LT</item>
    <item>352,LU</item>
    <item>853,MO</item>
    <item>389,MK</item>
    <item>261,MG</item>
    <item>265,MW</item>
    <item>60,MY</item>
    <item>960,MV</item>
    <item>223,ML</item>
    <item>356,MT</item>
    <item>692,MH</item>
    <item>222,MR</item>
    <item>230,MU</item>
    <item>262,YT</item>
    <item>52,MX</item>
    <item>691,FM</item>
    <item>373,MD</item>
    <item>377,MC</item>
    <item>976,MN</item>
    <item>382,ME</item>
    <item>212,MA</item>
    <item>258,MZ</item>
    <item>264,NA</item>
    <item>674,NR</item>
    <item>977,NP</item>
    <item>31,NL</item>
    <item>599,AN</item>
    <item>687,NC</item>
    <item>64,NZ</item>
    <item>505,NI</item>
    <item>227,NE</item>
    <item>234,NG</item>
    <item>683,NU</item>
    <item>850,KP</item>
    <item>47,NO</item>
    <item>968,OM</item>
    <item>92,PK</item>
    <item>680,PW</item>
    <item>507,PA</item>
    <item>675,PG</item>
    <item>595,PY</item>
    <item>51,PE</item>
    <item>63,PH</item>
    <item>870,PN</item>
    <item>48,PL</item>
    <item>351,PT</item>
    <item>1,PR</item>
    <item>974,QA</item>
    <item>40,RO</item>
    <item>7,RU</item>
    <item>250,RW</item>
    <item>590,BL</item>
    <item>685,WS</item>
    <item>378,SM</item>
    <item>239,ST</item>
    <item>966,SA</item>
    <item>221,SN</item>
    <item>381,RS</item>
    <item>248,SC</item>
    <item>232,SL</item>
    <item>65,SG</item>
    <item>421,SK</item>
    <item>386,SI</item>
    <item>677,SB</item>
    <item>252,SO</item>
    <item>27,ZA</item>
    <item>82,KR</item>
    <item>34,ES</item>
    <item>94,LK</item>
    <item>290,SH</item>
    <item>508,PM</item>
    <item>249,SD</item>
    <item>597,SR</item>
    <item>268,SZ</item>
    <item>46,SE</item>
    <item>41,CH</item>
    <item>963,SY</item>
    <item>886,TW</item>
    <item>992,TJ</item>
    <item>255,TZ</item>
    <item>66,TH</item>
    <item>228,TG</item>
    <item>690,TK</item>
    <item>676,TO</item>
    <item>216,TN</item>
    <item>90,TR</item>
    <item>993,TM</item>
    <item>688,TV</item>
    <item>971,AE</item>
    <item>256,UG</item>
    <item>44,GB</item>
    <item>380,UA</item>
    <item>598,UY</item>
    <item>1,US</item>
    <item>998,UZ</item>
    <item>678,VU</item>
    <item>39,VA</item>
    <item>58,VE</item>
    <item>84,VN</item>
    <item>681,WF</item>
    <item>967,YE</item>
    <item>260,ZM</item>
    <item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getCountry%28%29)

```
Locale locale = new Locale("de");
locale.getCountry();
```

Comment: thats the wrong way, I got the "germany" for example, but need the "de"

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but you can try this:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    if (locale.getDisplayCountry(Locale.US).equals("Netherlands")) {
        // Found !
    }
}
```

Now, there are a few caveats:

- is your input string spelled in english (if not, do you know the language?)?
- is the country you are looking part of a supported locale (if not this will not work)?