# Converting a country name to ISO Alpha 2 country code

Tags: android, locale, country-codes

I am using the country code picker library for user to select a country.
I stored the selected items with country name (i.e.: Singapore).
Now I want to convert the country name into ISO Alpha 2 country code (i.e.: sg).

I am using the Locale but it was not working, what am i missing?

```
public String getCountryCodeFromName(String countryName){
    Locale locale = new Locale("",countryName);
    String countryCode = locale.getCountry().toLowerCase();
    return countryCode;
}
```

Comment: have you googled it yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503225/get-country-code-from-country-name-in-android

Comment: the code was create after googled, but seems like i miss out the use of String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

Comment: It seems you stopped at the very first result you googled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`Use This Function:-`**

```
public String getCountryCode(String countryName) {

    // Get all country codes in a string array.
    String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
    String countryCode = "";
    // Iterate through all country codes:
    for (String code : isoCountryCodes) {
        // Create a locale using each country code
        Locale locale = new Locale("", code);
        // Get country name for each code.
        String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        if(name.equals(countryName))
          {
             countryCode = code;
             break;
          }
    }
    return countryCode;  
}
```

Comment: Dont really understand what is the purpose for using HashMap in this code?

Comment: Actually, HashMap Was For Storing All The Codes With Country Names As Key, Something Like This -> <Country Name, Country Code>, But Now I Have Edited The Code As Per Your Requirement.