# How to get country code from country name in React Native?

Tags: react-native

In Swift I would use locale, something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671829/get-country-code-from-country-name-in-ios). Android [seems also to have it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503225/get-country-code-from-country-name-in-android).

Is there a wrapper for this functionality for React Native?

Comment: this library may help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-country-code-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of little bits of data that you often need relating to countries, and I couldn't find any easy to use source of it. So I compiled it all here.

**Installing**

```
npm install country-data
```

[country-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data)

You can refer to the link above - it will help you to get all country with all the information to do mappings for country codes.

Answer (score 1):

well, in React Native there are a lot of third parties available for this, one that I have used is `react-native-country-picker-modal`. To install just run `yarn add react-native-country-picker-modal` or `npm install react-native-country-picker-modal` you can visit [this](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal) link